# Android Camera Capture button click

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-camera, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-broadcast

I am developing an app for a Bluetooth device in which I have to take a picture on Bluetooth button click.

I have coded for the receiver of BLE device and I get the button clicked event in receiver, But main problem is capture image code does not work.

I have tried following code in receiver

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent("android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON");
intent1.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_EVENT", new KeyEvent(0, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA));
sendOrderedBroadcast(intent1, null);
intent1 = new Intent("android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON");
intent1.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_EVENT", new KeyEvent(1, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA));
sendOrderedBroadcast(intent1, null);
```

I have also tried changing `KEYCODE_CAMERA` to `KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP` but this too do not work.

What do I code to get **camera capture button** event?

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

you should try doing like this.

```
 @Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //TODO
            }
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //TODO
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

or You can take reference from http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-working-with-camera-api/

Comment: I have already seen this but it is for my applications activity but It is not called in systems camera application

Comment: have u tried Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

Comment: This not what I want. It will open the camera and return the image to me in activity result. I want that when I press bluetooth button that is connected ,I want to Camera App to capture image.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera) to develop a camera app.

Refer sub section `Capturing pictures` which suggests to use [Camera.takePicture()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture(android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback)) method to capture image.

Comment: I don't want to do it in my application. I want that in captures image in systems camera application. Like when we press volume up button in systems camera app It takes picture. I want to do that when I press a bluetooth button.

Comment: I dont think that should be possible, because of security reasons; Unless camera application provides a way to do that, which unfortunately it does not. Can you elaborate more on your use case?

Comment: If you press volume plus button in camera application it captures image. I want to have same functionality but the thing is I have a bluetooth device "BCODA" which is connected to phone and I want to capture image on click of that bluetooth button.

Comment: here camera application is handling press of volume button and performing some action. camera application does not expose that action directly to be used by developers. Even if you emulate press of any button, that will be in scope of your application itself, camera application will have no effact to it. basically Android does not allows to emulate input to one application from another unless that application explicitly exposes a way to do that by broadcast reciever or any other such method.

Comment: Btw what are you trying to achieve after capturing the image? If you just want to save the catured image to gallary you can do that with your custom camera application.

Comment: Actually the device that I have is BCODA button which will be used as selfie button to capture image. Like a selfie stick captures image via bluetooth and we donot have to install any new application for that

Comment: as per their [official page](http://bcoda.com/codaclick) this thing works only with third party apps like candy camera. Anyways you are developing an app which needs to be installed in order to work with this device, Same app can have camera related implementation as well, and you will not need any additional app in order to achieve this use case. On other hand Selfie sticks either use camera apps timer or a custom camera app to achieve similar use case. we can have a chat over this if you need any further pointers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78188/discussion-between-sanjay-hirani-and-rahul-tiwari).